# Water Problems please help!

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, shower

So my water is dripping from both my shower and my kitchen sink even though it's off and I'm wondering how much will the water bill be? Will they still charge me even though its off? Help!

Comment: Water bill pricing is localized and cannot be answered.  This site is for asking "Do It Yourself" questions - a question on how to fix it would be appropriate.  This is not.

Answer (score 1):

The water company charges you based on the amount of water that flows through the water meter. The water meter doesn't know which valves are open or closed, it only knows that water is flowing through it.

Most places I've lived, bill based on cubic feet of water used (1 cubic foot of water = 7.48 gallons). There's also commonly a sewer charge if you're on public sewers, which is based on the amount of water used. Some places use a tiered pricing system, where the rates are lower if you use less water. For example, the first 1000-2000 cubic feet might be $1.80 per 100 cubic feet. The next 2001-3500 cubic feet might be $2.50 per 100 cubic feet. Then anything above 3500 cubic feet is $3.00 per 100 cubic feet.

You could use a [drip calculator](http://water.usgs.gov/edu/sc4.html) to figure out about how much water you're wasting, based on the number of drips per minute. Or you could repair or replace the leaking faucets, and stop wasting water.